# Getting net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

Can anyone help me with node js project? I am facing errors actually. When I will run my todo list app everything will run well. I used ejs, node js(express), MongoDB(mongoose) in my todo app. It will run fine but after some time of execution it will stop responding and nothing will happen no error anything. After waiting for some time resumed events will start executing. whatever I had did will execute and in browser console, it will show error "**POST http://localhost:3000/XXXXXX net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE**"
So if anyone know please help me

Comment: Please post the relevant reproducible code, Read [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to get visibilty and help from the community.

Comment: Thank you. But thing is that which cide should i paste here as cuz lots of code is their... If u do frequent response and request in node js web project do i feel like that?

Comment: Wait I will paste that screen shot if error I am getting